# Flink Sliding window does not work as expect

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, sliding-window

I have a datastream
1,2,3,4,5,6.....

Am applying sliding countWindow as below

inputStream.keyBy("id").countWindow( 2,1);

**Expected Output**

1,2

2,3

3,4 ..

**Actual Output**

1

1,2

2,3

3,4

Why does it slide first before accumulating the window size

Comment: The brave person who down voted this question. Care giving a comment?

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but I agree it is of very low quality. You should spend more time formatting your answer and also commenting on what all the dates mean.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the expected output you provided is wrong. You specified a window size to be 2 minutes. So the output(assuming it is start and end of a window) should be:

```
1:00:00, 1:01:00
1:01:00, 1:02:00
```

The first event with timestamp `1:00:00` should be assigned to windows `(0:59:00, 1:01:00)` and `(1:00:00, 1:02:00)`. I believe that answers your question.

After edit:

For the countWindow the same rule is applied. The first element belongs to two windows. It is easier to reason with a `countWindow(4,2)`. 
Have a look at a basic example:

```
val sEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
sEnv.setParallelism(1)

sEnv.fromCollection((1 to 10)).countWindowAll(4, 2).apply(
  (window, numbers, collector: Collector[Seq[Int]]) =>
    collector.collect(numbers.toSeq)
).print()

sEnv.execute()
```

The output is:

```
List(1, 2)
List(1, 2, 3, 4)
List(3, 4, 5, 6)
List(5, 6, 7, 8)
List(7, 8, 9, 10)
```

See that the first window that first element belongs starts in the past.

Comment: The problem was, it slides first before applying the actual window. Edited the question with countWindow for easier understanding

Comment: "The first element belongs to two windows" - Sorry cant get this point.
I could not understand , why its slides (2) elements first and then gathers (4) elements. The ideal way should be, first wait for 4 elements , and slide 2 elements. Simply, whatever number I give in "slide", that many number of elements appear first and then it proceeds normally

Answer (score 1):

I understood thanks to Dawid Wysakowicz's answer. I just wanted to add a figure hoping it could help understanding.

[image]

Indeed, in sliding windows, each element has to be entailed into 2 windows. That is, the first element has to be in 2 windows as well.

Comment: I understand this point.but am asking why. When I says countWindow(4). it  waits for 4 items. but when I says countWindow(4,2). it has to wait for 4 items and then slide two. Why it add imaginary numbers in front and make up a window which is not the given size

Comment: or simply if u can tell me how to achieve my "expected output" in the question

Comment: I am not sure but try to put an offset in your timeWindow (this is the third argument). I have never tried though.